# Can anyone explain these weird Compile Errors?

Tags: error-messages

So I've got some trigger code here that pop Compile Errors when I attempt to save it.

1.

```
String ED = Event.Description;
String Solution = ED.substringBetween('(',')');
```

> Error: Compile Error: Illegal assignment from Schema.SObjectField to String at line 11 column 5

2.

```
Booking__c NewBooking = new Booking__c (Check_In_Date__c = Event.StartDateTime, 
Check_Out_Date__c = Event.EndDateTime, Account__c = Event.AccountId);
```

> Error: Compile Error: Invalid initial expression type for field Booking__c.Check_In_Date__c, expecting: Datetime at line 16 column 10

(Check_In_Date__c is a Date/Time field. So is Check_Out_Date__c.)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: seems you are directly assigning the Object Fields to the variables. You have to query the Event records and then assign the field values from those records to your variables.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a variable named Event, the first one is a static reference to an SObject field via System.Schema.Event.Description. Make sure you're referencing a variable. The second error is related to the same problem. You don't have a variable that references a single Event, so it's resolving to the SObjectField reference (as above). In general, you should avoid naming variables to have the same name as a standard SObject to avoid this problem. This means not using variable names like Account, Case, Contact, or Opportunity. Both of your error messages would be resolved if you had a variable named event, such as:

```
for(Event event: Trigger.new) {
// Inside this loop, Event now refers to an event record in Trigger.new,
// and Schema.Event references the static SObject.
```